Quarkus GraalVM native build on Github Actions - Out of memory
I am currently using github actions to create a native build of and deploy, in a matrix, quarkus services. I am using github's hosted runners, tagged with ubuntu-latest that have 7G ram.
The problem is that approximately half of my services tend to fail during one of the 8 native build steps, reporting one of the following errors in a nondeterministic way, either after 20min to 1h, hinting to an exhaustion of memory:

Image generator watchdog detected no activity. This can be a sign of a deadlock during image building.
Caused by: io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep$ImageGenerationFailureException: Image generation failed. Exit code was 137 which indicates an out of memory error. Consider increasing the Xmx value for native image generation by setting the "quarkus.native.native-image-xmx" property
The message received from the daemon indicates that the daemon has disappeared.

Restarting the failed jobs until they are all successful is currently the way I fully deploy all services after a long while.
I have set a memory upper bound as per the command I use below to start the build, 6G being the sweet spot that seems to have the lowest amount of build errors (still one half of them). However, I can't go past this bound since the runners only have 7G ram and bigger runners are billed out of the enterprise plan's minutes on Github.
Is there a way, with these runners, to successfully and deterministically build the native image, even if it takes a longer while to do so?
The build step:
./gradlew ":${{ matrix.service }}:build" \
            --exclude-task test \
            -Dquarkus.profile="${{ env.PROFILE }}" \
            -Dquarkus.native.native-image-xmx=6g \
            "-Dquarkus.native.enabled=true" \
            "-Dquarkus.package.jar.enabled=false" \
            --stacktrace \
            -info

I am using the dockerized build from this image https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image#manually-using-the-minimal-base-image. Base image is also ubi-minimal:8.10, it uses nativeimage:23.1.2 from GraalVM and I could not reproduce the issue locally, I suspect because my laptop's RAM is greater than the 7G Github Action's runners are limited to.
I've also tried tuning gradle.properties's org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx6g and the command's -Dquarkus.native.native-image-xmx=6g with various values (from 2 to 6G, and one smaller than the other) and it either yields the same set of errors or something along the lines of Make sure you have enough memory when the arguments are set to low values.

There are many aspects for this to happen(quarkus version, linux version, glibc version,  have you tried in windows, can you get same error in your local), did you try with latest graalvm and can you put a reproducer to gitlab ? it will be easier to investigate that way

@ozkanpakdil Unfortunately I don't have much time to create a reproducer and wouldn't really know where to begin without sharing the code since I think part of the reason this error occurs is due to the project being quite big. (From what I understood, GraalVM takes up more RAM with bigger projects). I've edited my initial post with further details on the tools used.
